# Saving pygame display as pygame.Subsurface

Tags: python, pygame

I have created a program where small tiles are printed to the screen. The tiles are reprinted every iteration of my game loop. It works fine the way it is but I think it could cause problems if I used more tiles on a slower computer. My idea to improve it is save all the tiles as a joined subsurface rather than individual subsurfaces. That way I'd only have to print one subsurface to the display oppose to x many objects.[image] This is how the screen looks. **How do I save the screen as a subsurface?**

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that I get what you're saying here. Are the tiles static but you redraw them every iteration? If so, it does seem a shame to continuously redraw over and over.

Comment: @oxrock: The tiles do not move. it would be a lot more efficent to only reprint one big tile that was initialized to be made up of all the small tiles in the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's rather simple to accomplish this. First, take your map building operation out of the game loop and place it just before. Secondly, after the map has been blit (to what I'm assuming was your screen but any surface will work), simply hold that surface as a variable.

Example:

```
map = screen.subsurface(screen.get_rect())
```

Then at the end of your game loop, simply blit this map before blitting any other items.

```
screen.blit(map,(0,0))
screen.blit(player.image,(player.rect.x,player.rect.y))
for monster in monster_list:
    screen.blit(monster.image,(monster.rect.x,monster.rect.y)) # of course if you're using sprites, it's be best to just use  group.draw()
pygame.display.update()
```

This way all entities end up on top of your map surface.

Comment: Very nice solution! But I think you only need to use PyGames `.subsurface()` method when you blit the map onto the main screen surface.